# What is a numerical value in admission application context?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am applying to few universities (Master's degree) and one of them which is University of Helsinki is asking for numerical value included in computer science studies from my degree. Exact question:

> Please state the total amount of computer science studies included in your degree (numerical value, credits/study hours etc.)

My current degree is from Lithuania. I am confused about numerical value. Could somebody elaborate on this matter? In addition, any suggestions what else should I mention to answer this question fully?

Comment: What country is that university in?  This is probably some terminology specific to that country's education system.  Also, what country is your current degree from?

Comment: Can you post the *exact* wording of the question? As is, it's difficult to figure out what specifically you are asking about.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've updated the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that they want to know how much of the total workload of your degree was dedicated to the topic of computer science. You're relatively free to choose in which way to quantify this workload (e.g. total number of hours of the courses on computer science), but since you're in Europe, my suggestion is to use [ECTS](https://ec.europa.eu/education/resources-and-tools/european-credit-transfer-and-accumulation-system-ects_en): you may be able to get the amount of ECTS credits for each course directly from your university student's guide.

Comment: To add clarity to this answer, by "numerical value, credits/study hours etc" they mean that *any* of those measures are appropriate, they are not requesting everything on that list plus more.